# Different operators in query string like ?var!=value

Tags: php, standards, standardization, url

This one may actually be 2 questions in one.

Studying some APIs I came across an api suggesting to have operand different from equal (=) inside the query string (http://www.salesboard.com/api/):

```
mycompany.salesboard.com/api/contacts?CompanyId!=5
or
mycompany.salesboard.com/api/contacts?Id<=5
```

Is that possible?? and by "possible" I mean: is that legal according to the standards?
And if yes what are the possible problems to use such a url (compatibility, browser support, etc).

Now the second part of the question is: What is the best way to parse a URL such as this in PHP, has anyone ever used it?

PS: My question is not really problem but I thought it would be nice also for others to know.

Comment: I agree that a clean URL is much more "clean" but as @Bart said, the different operator url open a huge number of different possibilities. Making an API much more flexible. Anyway, the question was more theoretical, and less related to an API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard for URIs is [STD 66](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66), which currently maps to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

In [section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4), it is defined what the query component may contain. (Note that it can’t contain an unencoded `<`).

However, it does *not* define any meanings for characters (like `=`) that can appear in the query component. Using a format like `key=value` is just a convention as far as the general URI standard is concernced.

Specific [URI schemes](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml) might define such meanings, but the `http` URI scheme [doesn’t seem to](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.7.1).

So semantically, there is no difference between using `foo/bar`, `CompanyId!=5`, or `CompanyId-is-not-equal-to-5`. They are just characters and it’s up to the consumers to interpret them.

Comment: Agreed.  `=` only has semantic meaning insofar as it matches a key name to a value.

Comment: @unor: So what you are saying is that it's ok to do that. Right? What about the second part of the question: how can I interpret the sign in php?

Comment: @Aslabs: Yes, a query component like `CompanyId!=5` is valid in URIs. You can come up with any kind of string (as long as you percent-encode where necessary). // Unfortunately, I can’t say anything about parsing such a query component in PHP. (Maybe it might make sense to separate this second part about implementation into a separate question? No idea if it’s on-topic here or if it should be on [so].)

Comment: @unor: I have marked the answer as final because in fact or Amat also the seconds part of the question.

Comment: just remember that ! is not a valid character in a url... you'd need to encode this as 
`?CompanyId%21=5`

Comment: @N801: `!` [doesn’t have to be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38816380/1591669) percent-encoded in the query component